# Puppeteer и расширения

Tags: chrome-extension, puppeteer

пытаюсь запускать браузер вместе с расширением и постоянно выдает ошибки.
Этот код дает ошибку "Не удается загрузить расширение из... Не удается запустить javascript из...":

```html
    import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import path from 'path';

(async () => {
  const pathToExtension = path.join(process.cwd(), 'extension-3.1.0');
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: false,
    args: [
      `--disable-extensions-except=${pathToExtension}`,
      `--load-extension=${pathToExtension}`,
    ],
  });
  const page = browser.newPage();
  (await page).goto('https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/MAC-10%20%7C%20Lapis%20Gator%20%28Factory%20New%29')
  const backgroundPageTarget = await browser.waitForTarget(
    target => target.type() === 'background_page'
  );
  const backgroundPage = await backgroundPageTarget.page();
  // Test the background page as you would any other page.
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Этот код выдает "Файл манифеста отсутствует или недоступен для чтения"

```html
    const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    // Define the extension path
      const paths = './extension-3.1.0';
      try {
          console.log('==>Open Browser');
          // Configure the browser (Default Chromium Installation)
          const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
              headless: false,
              // Chrome options
              args: [
              `--disable-extensions-except=${paths}`,
              `--load-extension=${paths}`,
              `--window-size=800,600`
              ]
          });
  
          // Name of the extension
          const extensionName = 'iMacros for Chrome';
  
          // Find the extension
          const targets = await browser.targets();
          const extensionTarget = targets.find(({ _targetInfo }) => {
              return _targetInfo.title === extensionName && _targetInfo.type === 'background_page';
          });
  
          // Extract the URL
          const extensionURL = extensionTarget._targetInfo.url;
          console.log("\nExtracted URL ==>" + extensionURL);
          const urlSplit = extensionURL.split('/');
          console.log("Split URL ==>");
          console.log(urlSplit);
          const extensionID = urlSplit[2];
          console.log("Extension ID ==>" + extensionID +"\n");
  
          // Define the extension page
          const extensionEndURL = 'panel.html';
  
          //Navigate to the page
          console.log('==>Navigate to Extension');
          const page = await browser.newPage();
          await page.goto(`chrome-extension://${extensionID}/${extensionEndURL}`);
  
          console.log('==>Take Screenshot');
          await page.screenshot({path: 'chromium-extension.png'});
  
          console.log('==>Close Browser');
          await browser.close();
      }
      catch (err) {
          console.error(err);
      }
  })();
```